# Equivalence to Martin's Axiom

Tags: set-theory

I know that **MA** implies $2^\kappa = 2^{\aleph_{0}}$ for each cardinal $\kappa <2^{\aleph_{0}}$. Is the converse true? I mean, does $2^\kappa = 2^{\aleph_{0}}$ for every cardinal $\kappa <2^{\aleph_{0}}$ imply Martin's Axiom?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: MA does not imply CH, which you seem to be saying it does.  However, MA is a theorem in ZFC + CH.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Add a Cohen real to a model of MA. A name counting argument shows that $2^{< \mathfrak{c}} = 2^{\omega}$. MA fails because, for example, there is Suslin tree.

Comment: I don't think that it's quite common knowledge, yet, that adding a Cohen real adds a Souslin tree. So [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02760522) is the reference to Shelah's paper, proving this statement (unfortunately, it's behind a paywall).

Comment: Also, it should be pointed out that the result that MA fails after adding a Cohen real is originally due to Roitman, some considerable time before Shelah's Suslin tree result. Here is the reference: J. Roitman, _Adding a random or a Cohen real: topological consequences and the effect on Martin's axiom_, Fund.Math. **103** (1979), 1, pp. 47--60.

Comment: @Stefan: There is also a proof in Jech.